# SearchAPI + FacetAPI: Expose operator to user (AND/OR)

Tags: 7, search

In our project we have a requirement to exposed facet operator to user. On front end, user will see a bunch of facets and for each he will be able to select AND/OR operator. I'm looking for a way how to implement this.

I guess for this I would need to create custom widget for each facet to include AND/OR operator switcher. But I have no idea how to pass this operator to `search_api/search_api_solr`. Does facetsa allow operator to be set in GET parameter?

Current setup:
- [search_api: 7.x-1.14](https://www.drupal.org/node/2398657)
- [facetapi: 7.x-1.5](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi)
- [search_api_solr: 7.x-1.6](https://www.drupal.org/node/2334841)

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!